# error creating virtualenv in existing folder

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

```
$ virtualenv virtenv
Overwriting virtenv/lib/python2.7/site.py with new content
New python executable in virtenv/bin/python
Overwriting virtenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py with new content
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /virtenv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 245, in _get_queued_page
    page = self._get_page(location, req)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 335, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, cache=self.cache)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 452, in get_page
    resp = urlopen(url)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 85, in __call__
    response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_request(url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 396, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 258, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 245, in _get_queued_page
    page = self._get_page(location, req)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 335, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, cache=self.cache)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 452, in get_page
    resp = urlopen(url)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 85, in __call__
    response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_request(url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 396, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 258, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: /usr/share/python-virtualenv/

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 245, in _get_queued_page
    page = self._get_page(location, req)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 335, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, cache=self.cache)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 452, in get_page
    resp = urlopen(url)
  File "/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 85, in __call__
    response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_request(url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 396, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 258, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: .

Ignoring indexes: http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Downloading/unpacking distribute
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement distribute
No distributions at all found for distribute
Storing complete log in /home/collin/.pip/pip.log
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 3, in <module>
    virtualenv.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 993, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 961, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 903, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /virtenv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of pip in the existing virtualenv is outdated (version 1.1). upgrade it first:

```
./virtenv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

or just delete it:

```
rm ./virtenv/bin/pip*
rm -r ./virtenv/lib/python*/site-packages/pip*
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is going on and how that problem relates to what is printed to the terminal?

Comment: I actually have no idea. I just know that this fixed it for me. :) I think this happened when I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. Normally I would recreate a virtualenv directly on top of an existing virtualenv so it would get the new python version. In this case though that doesn't work and I needed to delete pip first.

Comment: inside the virtualenv, it tries to use its copy first. If you remove it, it will use the host system's copy instead, which works properly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
virtualenv <venv> --no-{pip,wheel,setuptools}
<venv>/bin/pip install -U pip wheel setuptools
```

Recreating the venv first is necessary because I upgraded my system python from 2.7.3 (debian wheezy) to 2.7.9 (debian jessie), which broke the venv.